# Does "app" installed fresh app over current app?

Tags: appium

When I defined the "app" capability for the iOS driver in Appium, does Appium installed over the current installation of the app, or simply install the app if it does not currently exists on the device?

Cannot find the answer in the [documentation](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/).

Answer (score 0):

This behavior depends on whether you’re using the “fullreset” or “noreset” capabilities. For more information on those, see http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/other/reset-strategies/index.html#reset-strategies.